# 'NotFoundHttpException' in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, deployment, server, routes

I tried to upload my Laravel project using FTP, I did a composer update and changed server's PHP version to 7. But I'm getting a 'NotFoundHttpException' error. Can someone help me?Im just learning Laravel and deploying a project.I used hostinger. Thanks in advance.

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 179)

at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 548)

at Router->findRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 527)

at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 513)

at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 176)

at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)

at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)

at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)

at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)

at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)

at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 151)

at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)

at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 53)

```
<?php

Route::get('index', function () {
    return view('index.index');
});

Route::get('signup', function () {
    return view('auth.signup');
});

Route::get('choose-signup', 'EmployerLoginController@create');
Route::post('choose-signup', 'EmployerLoginController@store');

Route::get('register-emp', function(){
    return view('Auth.register-emp');
});

Route::post('register-emp', 'RegEmpController@store');

// --- 

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Auth::routes(); // --- 

// employer
Route::get('logs', 'Auth\EmployerLoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('logs', 'Auth\EmployerLoginController@login')->name('logss');


Route::get('employer', 'EmployerController@index')->name('emp');
// employer

// *******W O R K E X P E R I E N C E**************

Route::get('profile', 'WorkExperienceController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('profile/add','WorkExperienceController@store');
Route::get('resume', 'WorkExperienceController@create')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('resume/{id}', 'WorkExperienceController@update');
Route::get('resume/{id}', 'WorkExperienceController@destroy');

// **********E D U C A T I O N***********

Route::post('profile/added','AddEducationController@store')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('profile/{id}', 'AddEducationController@update');
Route::get('profile/{id}', 'AddEducationController@destroy');

//*********S K I L L S******************
Route::post('skill/added','AddSkillsController@store')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('skill/{id}','AddSkillsController@update');
Route::get('skill/{id}', 'AddSkillsController@destroy');


//********* S E M I N A R S******************
Route::post('profileaddsem','AddSeminarController@store')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('seminar/{id}','AddSeminarController@update');
Route::get('seminar/{id}', 'AddSeminarController@destroy');

//*********C O N T A C T I N F O******************


Route::get('jobseeker-signup', 'ContactInfocontroller@create');
Route::post('jobseeker-signup', 'ContactInfocontroller@store');
Route::post('contact/{id}','ContactInfocontroller@update');

Route::get('choose-signup2', 'JobseekerLoginController@index');
Route::post('choose-signup2', 'JobseekerLoginController@store');



// Route::get('/contact-info', function () {
//     return view('jobseeker-signup-partials.contact-info');
// });

// *****************I M A G E ***********************
Route::post('imgupdate','HomeController@update_avatar');

// ***************P O S T A J O B*************************

Route::get('jobsearch', 'PostJobController@index');
Route::post('jobsearch', 'PostJobController@index');

// ***************e d i t p o s t e d j o b************************

Route::post('posted/{id}', 'PostJobController@editJob');
Route::get('posted/{id}', 'PostJobController@destroy');


// ************J O B  P O S T******************
Route::get('jobpost/{id}','PostJobController@show');
// ****Click Apply**********
Route::post('jobpost','ApplicationController@store');
// ****Click Save**********
Route::post('save','ApplicationController@saveJob');
// ***********delete saved jobs*******************
Route::post('unsave/{id}','ApplicationController@destroy');

Route::get('applicants','PostJobController@applicants');

Route::post('pdf','WorkExperienceController@upload');


// ****************************************
Route::get('sendemail', function() {

    $data = array (
        'name' => 'Hello Email!',       

        );

        Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message){

        $message->from('cathcasumali@gmail.com','Hello');
        $message->to('caumali46@gmail.com')->subject('Hello');
        });

    return "Your email has been successfully sent";
});




Route::get('application', function(){
    return view('index.application');
});
Route::get('messages', function(){
    return view('index.messages');
});


// ***********E M P L O Y E R***********************

Route::get('employer-signup', 'EmployerSignupController@create');
Route::post('employer-signup', 'EmployerSignupController@store');


// Route::get('company-profile', 'PostJobController@create');
Route::post('employer/post', 'PostJobController@store');



// Route::prefix('employer')->group(function(){


//     Route::get('/login', 'Auth\EmployerLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('employer.login');
//     Route::post('/login', 'Auth\EmployerLoginController@login')->name('employer.login.submit');
//     Route::get('/', 'EmployerController@index')->name('company-profile');
// });



// Route::get('/login', function () {
//     return view('auth.login');
// });

// Route::get('/jobseeker-signup', function () {
//     return view('auth.jobseeker-signup');
// });
// Route::get('/company-profile', function(){
//     return view('index.company-profile');
// });


// Route::get('post', 'PostJobController@index');
```

Comment: Could you check the intended route is list in routes/web.php

Comment: Put the code of web.php, something is wrong^^

Comment: And with url you try to access and you get the error?, when you update the question, please put a comment and we will see you update it!

Comment: Hi, here is the url of my project "http://cathumali.890m.com/". It should show the homepage, unfortunately error occurs.
 Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't understand too good when your problem appears. You should put in question only information important. Problem, when appears, which url of web.php is executed, and then put the controller function too. Please update it.. i think i can help you. But need more specific info.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, i was trying to access this route:
Route::get('index', function () {
    return view('index.index');
});

I removed the '/' since based on my google research that i should remove it. I think i should fix my routes. Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment: 'Hi, here is the url of my project....', The route you are trying to access is `'/'`. By a quick glance of your routes file, this doesn't exist.

I tried http://cathumali.890m.com/index and this pointed me to what looked like a front page. If this is the intended page, I would suggest adding another route that either points to the same controller or fixing the routes to all point to index.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index.index');
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, originally, my route was written this way, 

Route::get('/index', function () {
    return view('index.index');
});

I removed the '/' since based on my google research that i should remove it. I think i have a problem with my routes. thank you.

Comment: Hi Cath, if my answer solved the problem, can you mark it answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As [mbozwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6030030/mbozwood) said in the comments: **two same URLs can exists with two different methods**.

---

I don't know if you can really create two routes with same URL but different method (GET and POST), like these ones:

```
Route::get('choose-signup', 'EmployerLoginController@create');
Route::post('choose-signup', 'EmployerLoginController@store');
```

Instead, use

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'choose-signup', 'EmployerLoginController@signup');
```

And in your controller method :

```
public function signup(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    { return redirect()->action('EmployerLoginController@store', ['request' => $request]); }
    else
    { return redirect()->action('EmployerLoginController@create'); }
}
```

It mays not to be the problem, but it is quiet weird.

Comment: As long as the method isn't identical, the route can have the same URL.


`Route::get('service-log', .....);` and  `Route::post('service-log', .....);`

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help, That's new to me. I think i could use it in my next project.. Thanks